# Add additional css class to Yii2 jui datepicker

Tags: php, html, css, jquery-ui, yii2

I am trying to make the text box of jui DatePicker in Yii2 look more like the other text boxes, by adding 'form-control' to the class name of the input control, when rendered.

I tried using clientOptions like this...

```
'clientOptions' => [ 'class' => 'form-control' ]

'clientOptions' => [ 'className' => 'form-control' ]
```

...and also as widget options, but am unable to figure this out.

Compared to Bootstrap Datetimepicker, the jui one looks really ugly.

Any ideas how I can add a class or make it look like other textboxes?

I have a simple datepicker, no fancy formattings, but am using it in my model.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Figured it out. It was simply...

```
'options' => ['class' => 'form-control']
```

Comment: thanks! i'm surprised this was such an obscure thing to find

Answer (score 0):

It may be given like this.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'client_name')->widget(
                    \yii\jui\AutoComplete::classname(), 
                    [
                        'options' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
                        'clientOptions' => [
                            'source' => ['USA', 'RUS'],
                        ],
                    ]
                )?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem but

```
'options' => ['class' => 'form-control']
```

did not work for me. I resulted to using the `CHtml` argument called [`$htmlOptions`](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/143/htmloptions-explained-for-various-controls) which is basically an array that holds the attributes of the HTML element and it worked for me.

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'form-control')
```